# An Elementary Approach to How Many Singular Points a Curve Can Have

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider an irreducible plane curve, $C \subseteq A^{2}_{\mathbb{C}}$. Prove that C has only finitely many singular points.

My idea is to consider the subset $S$ that contains the singular points of C. Then we would want to show that it is a closed subset--but I do not see where to go from here. Could someone help, with elementary methods?

Answer (score 6):

Hint: The singular points should satisfy some equation, and so should be Zariski closed. That means they are either everything or finite (why?). But, they can't be everything (why?).

Comment: This is a good hint.

Comment: For an irreducible curve, the only closed subsets are a finite set of points or the curve itself. They cannot be everything because the set Zariski closed set has a polynomial which is of lower degree, and therefore less roots.